# Version of consul

Tags: jhipster

When I generate a microservice project the consule docker-compose file suggests version 0.9.7 of the docker docker image.

Would it be ok to use the most recent version which is version 1.0.7, or is there a specific reason for version 0.9.3 ?

Comment: JH 5 beta uses 1.0.x and it required some changes : see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6970 and https://www.jhipster.tech/2018/04/03/jhipster-release-5.0.0-beta.0.html

Comment: ok, so better stick with version 0.9.3

Comment: Or try beta 5.0